# Вебсокеты и bitfinex

Tags: javascript, websocket

Хочу использовать вебсокеты для получения курса валют с биржи битфинекс. Но в браузере получаю ошибку

```
<html>
<div id="btc"></div>
<script>
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://api2.bitfinex.com:3000/ws");
ws.onopen = function(){
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({"event":"subscribe", "channel":"ticker", "pair":"BTCUSD"}))
};
ws.onmessage = function(msg){
  var response = JSON.parse(msg.data);
  var hb = response[1];
  if(hb != "hb"){
    document.getElementById("btc").innerHTML = "$" + response[7];
  }
};
</script>
</html>
```

Ошибка

```
failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Вывод таблицы с помощью php

```
$req = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/book/BTCUSD"), true);
echo "<table><tr><td>Bids</td><td>Asks</td></tr>";
$bids = $req["bids"];
echo "<tr><td valign='top'>";
foreach($bids as $details){
    echo "$".$details["price"]." - ".$details["amount"];
    echo "<br>";
}
echo "</td><td valign='top'>";
$asks = $req["asks"];
foreach($asks as $askDetails){
    echo "$".$askDetails["price"]." - ".$askDetails["amount"];
    echo "<br>";
}
echo "</td></tr></table>";
```

Ордербук

```
  <script>
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://api-pub.bitfinex.com/ws/2");


  ws.onopen = function(){ 
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({ event: 'conf', flags: 131072 }))
 let msg = JSON.stringify({ event: 'subscribe', channel: 'book', pair: 'tBTCUSD', prec: 'P0' })
ws.send(msg)


 ws.onmessage = function(msg){
  var response = JSON.parse(msg.data);   
  console.log(response);
}
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Судя по ответам hb это состояние когда не нужно обновлять значение?]
Судя по ответам hb это состояние когда не нужно обновлять значение?

Возможно у вас проблема c элементом `<div id="btc"></div>`

Comment: а как мне в таком случае выводить информацию?

Comment: у вас не совсем правильно был записан доступ к 7 элементу. Вот верный.
`document.getElementById("btc").innerHTML = "$" + response[1][7];`

Comment: Cпасибо, есть еще вопрос. На пхп написан скрипт, выводящий ордер бук, также с битфинекса, как это можно реализовать с помощью вебсокетов? Дополнил ответ своим php кодом

Comment: https://docs.bitfinex.com/v2/reference#ws-public-order-books
Вам просто нужно немного поменять параметры в ws.send и потом правильно распарсить ответ в таблицу, как у вас сделано на php

Comment: А как можно текущий курс btc вывести? в паре с долларом

Comment: А как можно текущий курс btc вывести? в паре с долларом

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.bitfinex.com/v2/docs/ws-general

В API Docs указазно:

```
// For public channels:
wss://api-pub.bitfinex.com/ws/2

// For authenticated channels:
wss://api.bitfinex.com/ws/2
```

Используйте первый URL для ваших запросов.

Comment: Поменял url, сейчас на странице высвечивается $undefined и все

Comment: Я не проверял дальше прихода ответа. Сейчас посмотрю

Comment: а вы не могли бы посмотреть?

Comment: Можете показать, как вывести ордер бук? Дополнил ответ кодом, никак не получается вывести его.